# I have an error in some basic XNA 4.0 code

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0, pong

I am new to XNA and found a tutorial online for making a pong like game using it.I am going through the tutorial but I am getting an error even though it is the exact same code.Here is my Game1.cs* code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace WindowsGame1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main type for your game
    /// </summary>
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        Paddle paddle;
        Rectangle screenBounds;

        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
            screenBounds = new Rectangle(
            0,
            0,
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth,
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
        /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
        /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
        /// and initialize them as well.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

            base.Initialize();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
        /// all of your content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
            Texture2D tempTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("paddle");
            paddle = new Paddle(tempTexture, screenBounds);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
        /// all content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
        /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            // Allows the game to exit
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                this.Exit();
            paddle.Update();
            base.Update(gameTime);
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
            spriteBatch.Begin();
            paddle.Draw(spriteBatch);
            spriteBatch.End();
            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }

    }
}
```

I also have this class

```
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
namespace BreakingOut
{
 class Paddle
 {
 Vector2 position;
 Vector2 motion;
 float paddleSpeed = 8f;
 KeyboardState keyboardState;
 GamePadState gamePadState;
 Texture2D texture;
     Rectangle screenBounds;
 public Paddle(Texture2D texture, Rectangle screenBounds)
 {
 this.texture = texture;
 this.screenBounds = screenBounds;
 SetInStartPosition();
 }
 public void Update()
 {
 motion = Vector2.Zero;
 keyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();
 gamePadState = GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One);
 if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
 motion.X = -1;
 if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
 motion.X = 1;
 if (gamePadState.ThumbSticks.Left.X < -.5f)
 motion.X = -1;
 if (gamePadState.ThumbSticks.Left.X > .5f)
 motion.X = 1;
 motion.X *= paddleSpeed;
 position += motion;
 LockPaddle();
 }
 private void LockPaddle()
 {
 if (position.X < 0)
 position.X = 0;
 if (position.X + texture.Width > screenBounds.Width)
 position.X = screenBounds.Width - texture.Width;
 }
 public void SetInStartPosition()
 {
 position.X = (screenBounds.Width - texture.Width) / 2;
 position.Y = screenBounds.Height - texture.Height - 5;
 }
 public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
 {
 spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, Color.White);
 }
 public Rectangle GetBounds()
 {
 return new Rectangle(
 (int)position.X, 
 (int)position.Y, 
 texture.Width,
 texture.Height);
 }
 }
}
```

this code so far is just for creating a paddle that the user can move.I also have an image of the paddle loaded in properly.This is the error it produces:

```
The type or namespace name 'Paddle' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

This is the part producing this error:

```
Paddle paddle;
```

I have done exactly what the tutorial has said to do and it worked for whoever made the tutorial.Any help would be hugely appreciated and if you need more info just ask.Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The Paddle class is inside the "BreakingOut" namespace, which is not referenced on your Game1 class.

So you can either add the "using BreakingOut" before the Game1 class, or change the namespace of Paddle.

Option 1 would look like this:

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

using BreakingOut;     // Add the namespace of the object!!!!!

namespace WindowsGame1
```

Option 2 would be:

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
namespace WindowsGame1    // Change the namespace of your object!!!!!
{
 class Paddle
 {
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a reference to your Paddle class namespace, but if the Paddle class is in the same project just rename the namespace to WindowsGame1.

Answer (score 0):

as Jason struckholf is saying to change namespace of paddle class 
use this code

```
using System.Text;
   using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
   using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
namespace  WindowsGame1
{
 class Paddle
 {
 Vector2 position;
 Vector2 motion;
 float paddleSpeed = 8f;
 KeyboardState keyboardState;
 GamePadState gamePadState;
 Texture2D texture;
     Rectangle screenBounds;
 public Paddle(Texture2D texture, Rectangle screenBounds)
 {
 this.texture = texture;
 this.screenBounds = screenBounds;
 SetInStartPosition();
 }
 public void Update()
 {
 motion = Vector2.Zero;
 keyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();
 gamePadState = GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One);
 if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
 motion.X = -1;
 if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
 motion.X = 1;
 if (gamePadState.ThumbSticks.Left.X < -.5f)
 motion.X = -1;
 if (gamePadState.ThumbSticks.Left.X > .5f)
 motion.X = 1;
 motion.X *= paddleSpeed;
 position += motion;
 LockPaddle();
 }
 private void LockPaddle()
 {
 if (position.X < 0)
 position.X = 0;
 if (position.X + texture.Width > screenBounds.Width)
 position.X = screenBounds.Width - texture.Width;
 }
 public void SetInStartPosition()
 {
 position.X = (screenBounds.Width - texture.Width) / 2;
 position.Y = screenBounds.Height - texture.Height - 5;
 }
 public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
 {
 spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, Color.White);
 }
 public Rectangle GetBounds()
 {
 return new Rectangle(
 (int)position.X, 
 (int)position.Y, 
 texture.Width,
 texture.Height);
 }
 }
}
```